# python - setting property of class on module loading

Tags: python, properties

I'm working on a code dealing with dict data on python.
 While implementing such class, I have to define a lot of properties. It's not that hard, but recently I thought it would be much better if I could use something like helper function.

For example, let's assume that I have a class like the following.

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @property
    def version(self):
        return self.data["version"]
```

If I could write this class in something like the following.

```
 class MyClass(object):

     def __init__(self, data):
         self.data = data

     define_own_property("data", "version")
```

It looks trivial, but if I can do that, I think I can reuse a lot of validation/exception handling cases.

Any idea? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve something like that by just writing a function to return the accessor you want:

```
def define_own_property(attr, key):
    def prop(self):
        return getattr(self, attr)[key]
    return property(prop)

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    version = define_own_property("data", "version")
```

Note that you must do `version = ...`  There is no way to make a simple function call `define_own_property` add a property to the class being defined, because that class doesn't yet exist so you can't reference it.

Another possibility is to give your class an attribute that is a list or dict or something containing the relevant parameters ("data", "version", etc.), then write a class decorator that reads these parameters and auto-creates the series of properties.  This would remove the need to define the properties inside the class at all; you would just give a list of the things you wanted the properties to access, and use the decorator once on the class.

Comment: This is nice.  I think I like it more than mine.

Comment: @mgilson: Heh, thanks.  Yours is basically the same thing except instead of using `property`, you essentially re-implemented `property` but with the specific get-key-of-attr behavior built in.

Comment: I know.  That's why yours is better.  Why reinvent the wheel?  But I'm leaving mine because I guess it's good to see an actual example of a descriptor.  (and because people upvoted it for some reason ...)

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting more used to python's 'everything is an object' concept. Simple and nice.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you could use a descriptor:

```
class Descr(object):
    def __init__(self,attr,key):
        self.attr = attr
        self.key = key

    def __get__(self,obj,type=None):
        return getattr(obj,self.attr)[self.key]

    def __set__(self,obj,value):
        getattr(obj,self.attr)[self.key] = value

    def __delete__(self,obj):
        del getattr(obj,self.attr)[self.key]

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    version = Descr("data","version")
    foobar = Descr("data","foobar")

a = MyClass({})
a.version = 1
print a.version
a.foobar = 'string'
print a.data
```